# Merge [firebase-security] and [firebase-security-rules]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Can [firebase-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-security) (1649 questions) and [firebase-security-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-security-rules) (113 questions) be merged?

Both have practically the same description.  There is currently a synonym proposal on [firebase-security-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-security-rules), but seeing that the tag only has 6 users eligible to vote on the proposal, I doubt it will happen anywhere in the near future.