# Rename [firebase-database] to [firebase-realtime-database]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Can the tag [firebase-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-database) be renamed to [firebase-realtime-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database)?

As the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firebase-database/info) states the tag is for Firebase Realtime Database and since the arrival of [google-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore), a different kind of database from Firebase, there have been an increasing amount of questions about Firestore tagged with [firebase-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-database). The reason for the mistagging is the fact that Firebase has multiple kinds of databases and a general name like *"firebase-database"* doesn't describe wich type of Firebase database it is about

To avoid these mistakes from now on I suggest the tag [firebase-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-database) be renamed to [firebase-realtime-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database).

Comment: So, because people are mist-tagging "firestore" questions, you want "firebase" to be renamed?

Comment: @Cerbrus The reason for the mistagging is the fact that Firebase has multiple kinds of databases and a general name like _"firebase-database"_ doesn't describe wich type of Firebase database it is about. I will include this in my question in a min.

Comment: I favor this change. But. If we are sticking with naming conventions then *google-cloud-firestore* is appropriate and then so is *google-realtime-database*

Comment: @Jay The name i proposed is in the current tag info which in turn comes from [firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

Comment: Oh. My apologies. My comment was supposed to be a comment to the answer by ivan to follow "vendor-product" form. Either way, I agree with you there's a lot of crossover tag use between the different products. I get storage questions in the firebase-database tag and cloud-firestore questions in the Firebase-database tag etc. Then we have the generic Firebase tag which is a catch all. More clearly defining which database is being used via a more descriptive tag is a great idea.

Comment: Thanks for requesting this change André. And thanks for making the change so quickly @BhargavRao. Even after only a few days, I can already see a reduction in mistagged questions. 

Comment: That's some really good news @FrankvanPuffelen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [firebase-realtime-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database) tag sounds good to me. It's definitely been more work to retag the wrong "[firebase-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-database) on a [google-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore) question" tags.

Any reason why we can't do this through a synonym though? If we just create the new tag, start using that, and then define the old tag as a synonym. We've done that with [firebase-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-functions) (maps to [google-cloud-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-functions)) and [firebase-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-firestore) (maps to [google-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore)) too and the problem was quickly solved on those cases (although surprisingly not for [firebase-security-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-security-rules)).

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. I posted it here because I only had the experience of the firebase-security-rules synonym as shown in [my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366255/merge-firebase-security-and-firebase-security-rules) about that.

Comment: The tag has been renamed after the top user of the tag (Frank van Puffelen) has confirmed that the tag rename would be fine.

Comment: @BhargavRao Do you see any problem with us defining `firebase-database` as a synonym?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Nope, added it as a synonym. Should take 3 minutes for the cache to clear and the change to reflect everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao! And thanks André for raising this.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Choose a Database: Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database  |  Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore), the official product names are now *"Cloud Firestore"* and *"Realtime Database"*.

As such, the suggested tags look like the optimal choice: they are both in the straightforward form of *"vendor-product"* -- which is as clear as we can get in this situation of similarly-named products.